# Poor WiFi signal with Raspeberry Zero W

Tags: wifi

I have recently bought Rasberry Zero W. Since I wanted to get original top quality item I bought it at **PiHut**.

Nevertheless, I still have problems with the unit; as it has incredibly poor WiFi signal. When about **2 m from the AP** (one wall in between), signal power is only **-72dBm to -82dBm** depending on the unit orientation, as checked by `iwconfig` command.

I have tried two different SDcards, two different power supplies, without significant change. I also put my Raspberry Pi 3 on the same spot, signal power is **-56dBm** (I haven't tried different orientations, just for comparison).  Finally using Wifi Analyzer for Android on my smartphone (Galaxy S10E), signal power is around **-45dBm**.

Is such small signal normal for Raspberry Zero W? Should I perhaps asked for a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought another Raspberry Pi Zero W.

With the same power supply, the same SD card as the first Raspberry Pi Zero W and on the same spot, signal is **-44dBm** to **-49dBm**. This is better than Raspberry Pi 3 and comparable to my smartphone.

The first Raspberry Pi Zero W is obviously faulty and I will send it back.